# Get param of edit route (/foobar/2/edit)

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I wonder how to get the param (the ID) of my edit route in Ember.js.

That's how I defined my route:

```
this.resource('accounting', function() {

  this.resource('accounting.requests', { path: '/requests' }, function() {
    this.route('new');
    this.route('archived');
  });
  this.resource('accounting.request', { path: '/request/:request_id' }, function() {
    this.route('edit');
  });

});
```

Now I want to fetch the model by its ID on this edit route `/accounting/request/3/edit`:

```
App.AccountingRequestEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('request', params.request_id);
  }

});
```

But this doesn't work because `params` is empty.

This works as expected, but the edit route doesn't:

```
App.AccountingRequestRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('request', params.request_id);
  }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are in a child route you can use `this.modelFor`, example:

```
App.AccountingRequestEditRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function(params) {
    return this.modelFor('request');
  }

});
```

Because in order to go to `request.edit`, you have to provide an id or object to its parent resource, `request` either directly going to the route passing the url to the browser or indirectly by transition from other routes that happen to link to edit.